# Assign a 2d array to a 4d array with a mask in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a 4d mask of size (H,W,H-h+1,W-w+1), where mask[:,:,dh,dw] denotes a mask for a sliding window of size hxw with shift (dh,dw) from top-left corner of an image.

Example:

```
>>> mask[:,:,0,0]
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

>>> mask[:,:,1,1]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to put some matrix of size hxw on positions denoted by mask. My problem is that I don't know how to assign a 2d array to a 4d array with a 4d mask.

For example, for the matrix

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

The result I expect for the shift (0,0) would be

```
>>> result[:,:,0,0]
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: How making a `result` array with the right shape and dtype, and then assign each `[:,:,i,j]` block?

Comment: @hpaulj Want to do this without for loops

Comment: Ah yes, the magic :without loops" qualifier :)  It may be possible to use broadcasting to do this, may be expanding the dimensions of the 2d to 4d etc.  But I'd have to experiement, and without an easy to create mask, I'm not too inclined to take the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if numpy has an easy way to do this with a mask. So if that's absolutely necessary, I can't help you!

If you are instead okay with indexing directly, you can use some magic voodoo art ;) like the following:

```
# Setup
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

H, W, h, w = 10, 12, 4, 5
out = np.zeros((H, W, H - h + 1, W - w + 1), dtype=int)
arr = np.arange(1, h * w + 1).reshape(h, w)

# Create an index for each dimension
# a = [0, 1, ..., 10]
# b = [0, 1, ..., 12]
# etc...
a, b, c, d = map(np.arange, out.shape)

# Index the output array with 4 indexers:
out[
    swv(a, h)[:, None, :, None],  # Use a sliding index for the
    swv(b, w)[None, :, None, :],  # first two dimensions.
    c[:, None, None, None],       # Index the latter two dimensions normally, except
    d[None, :, None, None],       # such that they broadcast with the sliding windows.
] = arr                           # Assign your array to the indexed output
```

Some outputs:

```
>>> out[:, :, 1, 1]
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
>>> out[:, :, 4, 6]
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a smaller case, with a (4,4,2,2) mask.  The (2,2) size is just for demonstation purposes.

The (2,2) array we want to insert:

```
n [54]: arr= np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)
```

The mask, with only 2 of the subarrays sets.  Doesn't matter whether its bool or int. The int version displays more compactly:

```
In [55]: mask = np.zeros((4,4,2,2),int)    
In [56]: mask[:2,:2,0,0]=1; mask[1:3,1:3,1,1]=1

In [57]: mask[:,:,1,1]
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The target arrays - same size as mask:

```
In [58]: res = np.zeros(mask.shape,int)
```

The nonzero, where`, indices are, I think, more useful than the bool mask:

```
In [59]: idx = np.nonzero(mask)    
In [60]: idx
Out[60]: 
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

These 8 nonzero values select 8 elements from `res`:

```
In [61]: res[idx]
Out[61]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Replicate `arr` to match.  I don't often use `resize`, but here it does just I want:

```
In [62]: arr1=np.resize(arr,idx[0].shape);arr1
Out[62]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])    
In [63]: res[idx]=arr1
```

Check the result:

```
In [64]: res[:,:,0,0]
Out[64]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [65]: res[:,:,1,1]
Out[65]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

There's probably a lot of overlap between what I've demonstrated and the other answer(s), but I've tried to keep things direct and simple.